# Dozer mapping to an entity class which has a composite primary key

Tags: java, jpa, dozer

The main entity class is 'Order'.
I have created a jpa entity class say 'OrderPK' for a composite primary key(orderId,orderName). 
I am mapping another class to the 'Order' class  using Dozer mapping.However, dozer is not mapping values from the main class to the Order class for the composite primary key entites(orderId,orderName).It is setting null values for the composite primary key values(orderId,orderName).Why is this so?

Comment: I fixed it up thank you. There was a missing @Mapping annotation on the primary key elements.